# How best to embed various cell groups into a $\LaTeX$ project?

Tags: front-end, formatting, latex

I'm an author and a coder. I want to reference various parts of my notebooks in my $\LaTeX$ project. I've tried doing the following, using a post on [the $\LaTeX$ side of this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex).

[image: example]

I'd like to solve it from the *Mathematica* side with some sort of automated exporting/embedding so I don't have to typeset each box in the `BoxForm` of my cells.   I'm looking for a better unified way of more tightly and elegantly coupling pieces of my *Mathematica* work into my $\LaTeX$ projects:

Here are things I've already tried:

- Using hyperlinks to notebooks (too simple)
- Print the note as a PDF and embed it (printing in *Mathematica* is error prone)
- Manually export cells as images and include them as graphics (doesn't update when the code changes)

Comment: I'm working on "*Mathematica* side" that will export to TeX code compatible with my [mmacells](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells) package (one used in linked post). I think in this weekend I'll have a working solution.

Comment: @jkuczm I'm excited! How do you plan on handling graphic output?

Comment: At the moment my main concern is "ordinary code", so I don't plan anything sophisticated for graphics, just automatic export of `Graphics...Box` to PDF and inclusion in TeX, in `mmaCell` environment or using `\mmaCellGraphics` if whole cell is just graphics. In the distant future maybe writing [Mathematica2tikz](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2377/14303) would be interesting, but this seems a lot of work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Introduction

Below I present usage of my [CellsToTeX](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX) package.

It provides functions for converting *Mathematica* cells to $\TeX$ code
compatible with $\TeX$ package [mmacells](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells).
Compilation of this $\TeX$ code results in output resembling FrontEnd appearance of converted cells.
Full capabilities of $\TeX$ package are described in my
[post in "Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX" thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223898/70587)
on TeX StackExchange.

Converted code preserves formatting and has special annotations reflecting colorization of identifiers.
The latter feature is provided by [SyntaxAnnotations](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaSyntaxAnnotations)
package, described in an
[answer to "How to convert a notebook cell to a string retaining all formatting, colorization of identifiers etc?" question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/74105/14303).

---

## Usage examples

Import package without installation:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX/master/NoInstall.m"]
```

### Individual cells

Default conversion of `"Input"` cell preserves formatting:

```
testCell = Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Subscript[x, 1] == (-b \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)]], "Input"];
testCell // CellPrint
CellToTeX[testCell]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  \mmaSub{x}{1}==\mmaFrac{-b\(\pmb{\pm}\)\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{b}{2}-4 a c}}{2 a}
\end{mmaCell}
```

Same cell converted to `"Code"` $\TeX$ cell. By default this conversion changes boxes to `InputForm`:

```
CellToTeX[testCell, "Style" -> "Code"]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}{Code}
  Subscript[x, 1] == (-b \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/(2*a)
\end{mmaCell}
```

Conversion of boxes with some colored symbols:

```
MakeBoxes[Table[Sin[x], {x, 10}]; Module[{x = 1, a}, a[y_] := x + y]] // DisplayForm
CellToTeX[%, "Style" -> "Code"]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={x},morelocal={a},morepattern={y_, y}]{Code}
  Table[Sin[x], {x, 10}]; Module[{\mmaLoc{x} = 1, a}, a[y_] := \mmaLoc{x} + y]
\end{mmaCell}
```

Note that commonest syntax roles of symbols are set as environment's options,
only non-commonest roles require code annotations.

### Whole notebook

Let's start with creating an example notebook with some evaluated cells:

```
nbObj = CreateDocument[{
    Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes[Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]], "Input"],
    Cell[
        BoxData[{
            MakeBoxes[Module[{x = 3}, x + 2]],
            MakeBoxes[f[x_] := 2 x + 1],
            RowBox[{"Print", "[", 
            RowBox[{"\"Print a string with a fraction \"", ",", RowBox[{"a", "/", "b"}], ",", "\" inside\""}], "]"}],
            RowBox[{"1", "/", "0"}],
            RowBox[{RowBox[{"1", "+", RowBox[{"2", " ", "x"}]}], "//", "FullForm"}]
        }]
        ,
        "Input"
    ]
}];
(* Swich off auto deleting of labels, so that we can extract some data from them. *)
CurrentValue[nbObj, CellLabelAutoDelete] = False;
SelectionMove[nbObj, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nbObj, Before];
```

#### Package default settings

Export above notebook to $\TeX$ using default settings:

```
SetOptions[CellToTeX, "CurrentCellIndex" -> Automatic];
ExportString[
    NotebookGet[nbObj] /. cell : Cell[_, __] :> Cell[CellToTeX[cell], "Final"],
    "TeX",
    "FullDocument" -> False,
    "ConversionRules" -> {"Final" -> Identity}
]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={x}]{Input}
  Solve[a \mmaSup{x}{2}+b x+c==0,x]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{\{x\(\to\)\mmaFrac{-b-\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{b}{2}-4 a c}}{2 a}\},\{x\(\to\)\mmaFrac{-b+\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{b}{2}-4 a c}}{2 a}\}\}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelocal={x},moredefined={f},morepattern={x_}]{Input}
  Module[\{x=3\},x+2]
  f[x_]:=2 \mmaPat{x}+1
  Print["Print a string with a fraction ",a/b," inside"]
  1/0
  1+2 \mmaUnd{x}//FullForm
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  5
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Print}
  Print a string with a fraction \mmaFrac{a}{b} inside
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[messagelink=message/General/infy]{Message}
  Power::infy: Infinite expression \mmaFrac{1}{0} encountered. >>
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[addtoindex=2]{Output}
  ComplexInfinity
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[form=FullForm]{Output}
  Plus[1,Times[2,x]]
\end{mmaCell}
```

Above $\TeX$ code results in following pdf:
[image: Print screen of pdf: default conversion]
Note that message link, in pdf, is clickable.

#### Example of customization

Convert `"Input"` cells to `InputForm` and export other cells as pdfs.

```
(* We'll be creating pdf files in notebook directory. *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
(* Add CellsToTeX`Configuration` to $ContextPath to get easy access to all "processors". *)
PrependTo[$ContextPath, "CellsToTeX`Configuration`"];
SetOptions[CellToTeX, "CurrentCellIndex" -> Automatic];
ExportString[
    NotebookGet[nbObj] /. {
        cell : Cell[_, "Input" | "Code", ___] :> Cell[CellToTeX[cell, "Style" -> "Code"], "Final"],
        cell : Cell[_, __] :> 
            Cell[CellToTeX[cell, "Processor" -> Composition[
                trackCellIndexProcessor, mmaCellGraphicsProcessor,
                exportProcessor, cellLabelProcessor, extractCellOptionsProcessor
            ]], "Final"]
    },
    "TeX",
    "FullDocument" -> False,
    "ConversionRules" -> {"Final" -> Identity}
]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={x}]{Code}
  Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]
\end{mmaCell}

\mmaCellGraphics{Output}{c6a8671c.pdf}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelocal={x},moredefined={f},morepattern={x_}]{Code}
  Module[{x = 3}, x + 2]
  f[x_] := 2*\mmaPat{x} + 1
  Print["Print a string with a fraction ", a/b, " inside"]
  1/0
  FullForm[1 + 2*\mmaUnd{x}]
\end{mmaCell}

\mmaCellGraphics{Output}{f86875a8.pdf}

\mmaCellGraphics{Print}{c2c36850.pdf}

\mmaCellGraphics{Message}{751e2ed3.pdf}

\mmaCellGraphics[addtoindex=2]{Output}{a88d6483.pdf}

\mmaCellGraphics[form=FullForm]{Output}{fdfe970a.pdf}
```

Above $\TeX$ code results in following pdf:
[image: Print screen of pdf: InputForm and included pdfs]
Note that you can copy code, from input cells in pdf, and paste it to *Mathematica*.

#### Mathematica built-in export

For comparison let's export same notebook using only *Mathematica*'s built-in `"TeX"` export.

To be able to export message cell we first need to [fix a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76802/14303):

```
If[FreeQ[Options[System`Convert`CommonDump`RemoveLinearSyntax], System`Convert`CommonDump`Recursive],
    DownValues[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex] =
        DownValues[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex] /.
            Verbatim[System`Convert`CommonDump`RemoveLinearSyntax][arg_, System`Convert`CommonDump`Recursive -> val_] :>
                System`Convert`CommonDump`RemoveLinearSyntax[arg, System`Convert`CommonDump`ConvertRecursive -> val]
];
```

Now we can export our example notebook:

```
ExportString[NotebookGet[nbObj], "TeX", "FullDocument" -> False]
```

```tex
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{Solve}\left[a x^2+b x+c==0,x\right]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}\right\}\right\}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{Module}[\{x=3\},x+2]}\\
\pmb{f[\text{x$\_$}]\text{:=}2 x+1}\\
\pmb{\text{Print}[\text{{``}Print a string with a fraction {''}},a/b,\
\text{{``} inside{''}}]}\\
\pmb{1/0}\\
\pmb{1+2 x\text{//}\text{FullForm}}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(5\)
\end{doublespace}

\noindent\(\text{Print a string with a fraction }\frac{a}{b}\text{ inside}\)

\noindent\(\text{Power}\text{::}\text{infy}: \text{Infinite expression }\frac{1}{0}\text{ encountered. }\rangle\rangle\)

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\text{ComplexInfinity}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\text{Plus}[1,\text{Times}[2,x]]\)
\end{doublespace}
```

Above $\TeX$ code results in following pdf:
[image: Print screen of pdf: built-in conversion]

### Unicode

Let's start with listing some ways of transferring non-ASCII characters from *Mathematica* to outside world.

If we just copy something to clipboard *Mathematica* will convert non-ASCII characters to `\[...]` form, if we don't want that to happen we can use one of ways described in [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/14303).

We can also directly `Export` to a file using appropriate, for our case, encoding e.g. `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"`.

In `CellsToTeX` package there are two options useful in customizing handling of non-ASCII characters: `"StringRules"` and `"NonASCIIHandler"`.

`"StringRules"` accepts list of rules used for replacing substrings with other substrings, so it can be used to directly replace certain character with something else.

Those non-ASCII characters that were not matched by `"StringRules"` will be handled by non-ASCII handler. `"NonASCIIHandler"` option accepts a function to which a `String` with non-ASCII character will be passed, it should return a `String` with "converted" character.

`CellsToTeX` package supports various different strategies for handling Unicode.

Let's create a test notebook with two cells contatining some non-ASCII characters:

```
testCells = {
    Cell[
        BoxData@MakeBoxes[Solve[a χ1^2 + β χ1 + γ == 0, χ1]],
        "Input"
    ]
    ,
    Cell[
        BoxData@MakeBoxes[{
            {χ1 -> (-β - Sqrt[β^2 - 4*a*γ])/(2* a)},
            {χ1 -> (-β + Sqrt[β^2 - 4*a*γ])/(2*a)}
        }],
        "Output"
    ]
};
testNb = Notebook[{Cell[CellGroupData[testCells, Open]]}];
% // NotebookPut;
```

#### Default

By default `"Code"` cells use `"NonASCIIHandler" -> Identity` which means that characters are unchanged by this conversion stage, but since it also uses `"CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII"` non-ASCII characters will be converted to `\[...]` form.

Other cell styles, by default use `charToTeX` function in `"NonASCIIHandler"` option, which converts characters to corresponding $\TeX$ commands, `"Input"` cells use `Bold` variant which additionally wraps commands with `\pmb{...}`, `"Output"`, `"Print"` and `"Message"` cells use `Plain` variant.

So default behavior is to always give pure ASCII result that will work in all $\TeX$ engines.

```
StringJoin@Riffle[CellToTeX /@ testCells, "\n\n"]
```

```tex
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  Solve[a \mmaSup{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\chi}\)1}}{2}+\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\beta}\)} \mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\chi}\)1}+\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\gamma}\)}==0,\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\chi}\)1}]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{\{\(\chi\)1\(\to\)\mmaFrac{-\(\beta\)-\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\(\beta\)}{2}-4 a \(\gamma\)}}{2 a}\},\{\(\chi\)1\(\to\)\mmaFrac{-\(\beta\)+\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\(\beta\)}{2}-4 a \(\gamma\)}}{2 a}\}\}
\end{mmaCell}
```

[image: Print screen of pdf: Unicode default]

#### Replacing Unicode at TeX level

Different strategy, which can be used with *pdfTeX* engine, is to use non-ASCII characters in $\TeX$ input and let $\TeX$ convert them to appropriate commands. On the level of `mmacells` package this is can be achieved using `\mmaDefineMathReplacement` command, in `CellsToTeX` those replacement can be gathered using `texMathReplacementRegister` function and appropriate `\mmaDefineMathReplacement` commands will be printed as part of preamble by `CellsToTeXPreamble` command.

```
Clear[texMathReplacement]
StringJoin@Riffle[
    Prepend[
        CellToTeX[#, "ProcessorOptions" -> {
            "StringRules" -> 
                Join[{"\[Equal]" -> "=="}, $stringsToTeX, $commandCharsToTeX],
            "NonASCIIHandler" ->
                (texMathReplacementRegister[Replace[#, "\[Rule]" -> "→"]] &)
        }] & /@ testCells,
        CellsToTeXPreamble[]
    ],
    "\n\n"
]
```

```tex
\mmaSet{morefv={gobble=2}}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{β}{\beta}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{γ}{\gamma}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{χ}{\chi}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{→}{\rightarrow}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  Solve[a \mmaSup{\mmaFnc{χ1}}{2}+\mmaUnd{β} \mmaFnc{χ1}+\mmaUnd{γ}==0,\mmaFnc{χ1}]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{\{χ1→\mmaFrac{-β-\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{β}{2}-4 a γ}}{2 a}\},\{χ1→\mmaFrac{-β+\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{β}{2}-4 a γ}}{2 a}\}\}
\end{mmaCell}
```

[image: Print screen of pdf: Unicode default]

Notice how we treated two private Unicode characters `\[Equal]` and `\[Rule]` differently. `\[Equal]` was simply converted to `==` using `"StringRules"`. `\[Rule]` was converted to `→` (`\[RightArrow]`) and still passed to `texMathReplacementRegister`.

Since resulting string contains non-ASCII characters, to transfer it from *Mathematica*, we must use one of methods described at the beginning of "Unicode" section.

#### Unicode-aware TeX engines

If you're using Unicode-aware $\TeX$ engine, e.g. *xetex*, you can simply use non-private Unicode characters from *Mathematica* in $\TeX$ input and output. But since automatic coloring of non-annotated identifiers in `mmacells` package relies on `listings` package, which doesn't work well with Unicode, this feature must be switched off, and all identifiers should be annotated. On the level of `CellsToTeX` package this can be achieved by switching off moving of commonest annotation types to $\TeX$ environments options (`"CommonestTypesAsTeXOptions" -> False`).

```
Clear[texMathReplacement]
StringJoin@Riffle[
    Prepend[
        CellToTeX[#, "ProcessorOptions" -> {
            "CommonestTypesAsTeXOptions" -> False,
            "StringBoxToTypes" -> {Automatic},
            "StringRules" -> 
                Join[
                    {"\[Equal]" -> "==", "\[Rule]" -> "→"},
                    $stringsToTeX, $commandCharsToTeX
                ],
            "NonASCIIHandler" -> Identity
        }] & /@ testCells,
        CellsToTeXPreamble["UseListings" -> False]
    ],
    "\n\n"
]
```

```tex
\mmaSet{uselistings=false,morefv={gobble=2}}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  Solve[\mmaUnd{a} \mmaSup{\mmaFnc{χ1}}{2}+\mmaUnd{β} \mmaFnc{χ1}+\mmaUnd{γ}==0,\mmaFnc{χ1}]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{\{χ1→\mmaFrac{-β-\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{β}{2}-4 a γ}}{2 a}\},\{χ1→\mmaFrac{-β+\mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{β}{2}-4 a γ}}{2 a}\}\}
\end{mmaCell}
```

[image: Print screen of pdf: Unicode xetex]

Since resulting string contains non-ASCII characters, to transfer it from *Mathematica*, we must use one of methods described at the beginning of "Unicode" section.

---

## Package design overview

In addition to main context, package provides also `` CellsToTeX`Configuration` `` context, with variables and functions useful for package customization.
All `` CellsToTeX`Configuration`* `` symbols are considered part of package public interface.

Package main context provides [`CellToTeX`](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX/blob/v0.2.0/CellsToTeX/CellsToTeX.m#L18-L22) function, which accepts whole `Cell` expressions or arbitrary boxes, reads options and passes all that data to a *Processor function*, that does the real work.
Processor is a function that accepts and returns list of options.
Since input of processor function has the same form as it's output, processor functions can be easily chained.

Processor function can be passed to `CellToTeX` in `"Processor"` option.
If this option is not given, `CellToTeX` extracts default processor from `"CellStyleOptions"` option.
This extraction is based on cell style, given explicitly as `"Style"` option or extracted from given `Cell` expression.

Currently package provides [11 processor functions](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX/blob/v0.2.0/CellsToTeX/CellsToTeX.m#L219-L380), from which [default processors, for different cell styles](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX/blob/v0.2.0/CellsToTeX/CellsToTeX.m#L1707-L1729), are composed.

Some processor functions accept options.
List of options for processors can be given to `CellToTeX` as value of `"ProcessorOptions"` option.
[Default values of processor options](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX/blob/v0.2.0/CellsToTeX/CellsToTeX.m#L1730-L1768) for different cell styles are extracted from `"CellStyleOptions"` option.

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded to this sooner. This is absolutely fantastic - WRI should pay you for this! I'd like to help do you have this in a github project yet?

Comment: thanks again for providing an excellent answer.

Comment: @M.R. I'm preparing new release of $\TeX$ package. It will contain some backward incompatible changes. I think I'll publish it in few days. After that I'll put adapted version of *Mathematica* package on GitHub.

Comment: @M.R. It took some time, but I think package is now in usable state. There are still some missing features, but I hope that package is easily extensible.

Comment: Beautiful, thumbs up!! Very grateful to have found this.

Comment: Amazing work! is there some way to enable automatic line breaks in `mmacells`?

Comment: @Casimir If you're ok with simple line breaks provided by `listings` package you can use [`morelst={breaklines=true}`](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/issues/22) option. As to smarter line breaking, adding a "Processor" using Leonid's [CodeFormatter](https://github.com/lshifr/CodeFormatter) is somewhere on my long TODO list.

Comment: @jkuczm Thank you, that works great! Is there also a way to control the indent of the `In[]` and `Out[]` labels? I feel like they are set too far right, thereby wasting space that could otherwise help to prevent some line breaks. Also I usually indent anything that appears inside an environment in $\LaTeX$. `mmacells` actually reflects this indentation in the amount of white space between the `In[]` and `Out[]` labels and the displayed Mathematica code. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: @Casimir You can decrease value of [`leftmargin` option](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/issues/35). There's also `labelsep` option controlling distance separating cell label from code.

Comment: @Casimir As to indentation inside environment in $\TeX$ code, you can remove it using `fancyvrb`s `gobble` option. By default `CellsToTeX` uses 2 spaces to indent contents of `mmaCell` environment, this is controlled by `"Indentation"` option of `mmaCellProcessor`. $\TeX$ command setting `morefv={gobble=2}` option should be automatically set by `CellsToTeXPreamble` function, but you can also change it manually.

Comment: @jkuczm One last question: What about referencing? I assumed the point of numbering the `mmaCell`s was to be able to reference them just like equations. Just tried this but doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Casimir Currently no referencing mechanism is built into `mmacells`. The point of numbering cells was to accurately reproduce *Mathematica* session with its cell indices. Since Input and following Output cells share cell index, and since you can embed multiple *Mathematica* sessions inside one $\TeX$ document, "raw" cell index counter is not good candidate to be referenceable. So currently you need some other referencable counter, in [issue 36](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/issues/36) I show how to "hook up" to listings labeling mechanism.

Comment: @Casimir I've added [example of references that automatically use cell labels as reference text](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/issues/36#issuecomment-344099257). Not sure if something like that is what you're after.

Comment: @jkuczm Very cool! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @jkuczm, Excellent answer. I am still unsure how I could write \delta using mmacells. I am struggling to get Greek letters into the environment. Any help?

Comment: @jkuczm, in fact, I would also like to write the operation \dagger in mmacells. Is this possible?

Comment: @Sid In "Unicode" sections of above answer and [TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223898/70587) there are examples of three ways of using Greek letters. Which variant are you using? What problems did you encounter? As to `\dagger`, you can use it inside `mmaCell` environment as any other TeX command, just remember that it's a math mode command, so it should be surrounded by `\(` and `\)`. If you want to automatically generate it using `CellsToTeX`, then what boxes are you converting?

Comment: @jkuczm, I got it working thank you! I used the script written below by Nicolas to understand how.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr: If you have a notebook you want to convert, put the following at the top of you notebook:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/\
MathematicaSyntaxAnnotations/master/SyntaxAnnotations/\
SyntaxAnnotations.m"]

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/\
MathematicaCellsToTeX/master/NoInstall.m"]
```

Then put this at the bottom of your notebook:

```
SetOptions[CellToTeX, "CurrentCellIndex" -> Automatic];
ExportString[
 NotebookGet[] /. 
  cell : Cell[_, __] :> Cell[CellToTeX[cell], "Final"], "TeX", 
 "FullDocument" -> False, "ConversionRules" -> {"Final" -> Identity}]
```

It will output the code as a text output IN your notebook. Copy-paste the code to your latex document. Add \usepackage{mmacells} to the top of your latex document, and put [this](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/blob/master/mmacells.sty) style file in your latex file's folder.

Comment: That makes it very easy to use!! Thank you!