# Convert Mathematica graphics to TikZ?

Tags: graphics, export, latex

Is there a package to convert Mathematica graphics to TikZ code (for inclusion in LaTeX source files)?

Such a package, dated 2016-01-30, is described at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/9554/ , but there seems to be no link there to any actual files.

I am aware of [Mathematica2tikz an equivalent function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2377/mathematica2tikz-an-equivalent-function).

I tried using eps an an intermediary but could not complete the process. Namely, I exported a simple graph `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}]` to EPS format. Then I tried to use the command-line utility `eps2pgf`, but that failed with Postscript error: "Feature not (yet) implemented: type 42 fonts"

Comment: Did you get this answer by other means? I'm interested too.

Comment: No, no answer so far.

Comment: even better: the Wolfram MathSource URL lists 'Will Thomson' at the University of Birmingham as its author.  Internal director at UoB doesn't find him.

Comment: The converter used within the ...2TikZ uses a frontend that unstands much but not all of Adobe PostScript language. Once the frontend knows the next graphics command to be executed, it then outputs the  equivalent TikZ command. Unfortunately, Type 42 font definition commands are part of what is missing. I strongly suggest using \includegraphics of a PDF instead.